# Is there anything special about the matrix $\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} e^{ix} & ie^{-ix} \\ ie^{ix} & e^{ix} \end{pmatrix}$ related to trigonometry?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

You can write the trigonometric formulas as such:

$$ \cos x = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2} $$
$$ \sin x = \frac{ie^{-ix}-ie^{ix}}{2} $$

This means you can write the rotation matrix as follows:

$$  \begin{pmatrix}
\cos x & -\sin x \\
\sin x & \cos x
\end{pmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
e^{ix}+e^{-ix} & ie^{ix}-ie^{-ix} \\
ie^{-ix}-ie^{ix} & e^{ix}+e^{-ix}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
e^{ix} & ie^{ix} \\
ie^{-ix} & e^{ix}
\end{pmatrix}
+
\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
e^{-ix} & -ie^{-ix} \\
-ie^{ix} & e^{-ix}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Do those individual matrices have a special name? Or special properties?

EDIT: you could make these matrices even nicer as follows:
$$z=e^{ix}$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
z & z' \\
z'^{-1} & z
\end{pmatrix}
+
\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
z^{-1} & (z^{-1})' \\
-z' & z^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Do you mean properties in the algebra of complex numbers or more properties in the hypercomplex algebras?

Comment: What you've done (modulo some issues with miswriting the formula for $\sin$ and missing a couple negative signs) is written each entry as $\frac{1}{2}\left( z + \overline{z}\right)$ for an appropriate $z \in S^1$ (i.e., $z \overline z = 1$), with the point being that $z$ is unique up to complex conjugation given the respective real number. "Up to complex conjugation" means there are 8 choices for how to do the matrix sum decomposition. One choice: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=eigendecomposition+of+%28%28e%5E%7Bix%7D%2C+ie%5E%7Bix%7D%29%2C+%28i+e%5E%7B-ix%7D%2C+e%5E%7Bix%7D%29%29

Comment: Your formula is missing the minuses.

Comment: I fixed $\sin$ and added the negatives.

Comment: The determinant of such matrices is not very appealing, I would rather split the sums while keeping $e^{ix},e^{-ix}$ on diagonals to keep the determinant $1$.